# Is there an ending that isn't death?

Tags: die2nite

Well I was just wondering, as some games that are meant to "end in death" or "endless" actually do have a end. Either it's the code can't go on or the game maker put in a "impossible" finish just for the hell of it as they would think no one could make it there. So, as the question states:

Is there an end to Die2Nite?